# What's the name of a number consisting of numbers separated by dot?

Tags: terminology, language-agnostic

I have been looking for a term to deal with a seemingly common pattern where a string consists of numbers separated by a `.` to *n* levels deep.

A prime example is Semantic Versioning numbers which are comprised of three numbers wherein `1.0.0` > `0.1.0`.

A project I am working on uses this pattern for identifiers for an *n*-level deep tree structure, such that `1` < `1.1` < `1.1.1` etc.

Is there a name for these strings? They aren't decimals, and the names “dot separated numbers” or “dot separated values” get me nowhere because of the dot separated values spec for spreadsheets.

Comment: Did you ever write outlines in school?  Same thing.  Microsoft word calls it a ["Multi-Level list."](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-multilevel-list-21a5f3cd-0be5-4319-9974-adb8cd376474) Typography for Lawyers calls it ["Hierarchical Headings using Tiered Numbers"](http://typographyforlawyers.com/hierarchical-headings.html).  Wikipedia calls it the ["Decimal Outline Format."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_(list)#Decimal_outline)  It doesn't really have much to do with programming.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I did indeed use it in school, but haven't had a name for it then or since. I was asking since I thought it might have a name in a programming context, since it is so widespread, especially for version numbering. In any case, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general term you are looking for is [***hierarchical numbering system/scheme***](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6RBX_11.4.3/com.ibm.sa.help.doc/topics/c_Add_Num_Hierarch_Diags.html):

- Hierarchical numbering consist of assigning a sequence of separated numbers (one number per level traversed) to identify uniquely an element in the tree.
- The most common hierarchical numbering system is the decimal one.

This kind of numbering scheme (i.e. data type) is rather general: it can be used to identify [headings and paragraphs](http://typographyforlawyers.com/hierarchical-headings.html) in documents, but it can also identify a position in an org-chart, an [XML node in an XML tree](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=21452418096E4E30E789C4828C3E6BE6?doi=10.1.1.368.411),  or a WBS element in a [work breakdown structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_breakdown_structure#Coding_scheme).